# F5 LTM on the same subnet

Tags: load-balancing, f5, big-ip

I am new to F5 BIG-IP, i can create the Virtual Server with pool and pool members to create a LTM for subnet A Virtual Server to subnet B servers.

But when i configure the Virtual Server to load balance the servers on the same subnet, it just not work, i can telnet the web server port 80 via the Virtual Server, but when i open it on web browser with the virtual ip, the page cannot be loaded.

The BIG-IP running at 9.3 version.

### WORKING (Different Subnet)

Virtual Server: 192.168.1.10
Web Server A: 192.168.2.11
Web Server B: 192.168.2.12

### NOT WORKING (Same Subnet)

Virtual Server: 192.168.1.10
Web Server A:   192.168.1.11
Web Server B:   192.168.1.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution ! when create Virtual Server, i use the default settings, the configuration is Basic, so there is no SNAT settings. Switch to Advance Configuration, and select SNAT: Auto Map. then it works ! your server can keep their default gateway to the firewall or switch.

Comment: If you don't use snat, the outbound traffic from the server needs to use the BIG-IP as the outbound gateway to preserve the route path.  SNAT allows you to ignore this and allow the traffic to use their existing gateways and outbound routes.  There's pro's and con's to each one.  Glad you got it sorted out.